# Change From Header using Mutt

Tags: mutt

I'm trying to send HTML email with an attachment using mutt. But I also have to set the From header to a custom email address. That part's not working.

Here is the command I'm trying to use:

```
echo $mail_body | mutt -e "set from=cloudops@noreply.company.com" -e "set content_type=text/html" -a "$ofile" -s "AWS Key Rotation Needed" -- $email_address
```

The HTML format, and attachment are working. How do I set the custom from header correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the custom email address you are speaking of is one of your configured mail accounts in mutt (account1). Simply load the corresponding configuration.

```
echo $mail_body | mutt -e "source ~/.mutt/accounts/account1" -e "set content_type=text/html" -a "$ofile" -s "AWS Key Rotation Needed" -- $email_address
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually I got this working since I posted this. I forgot to update the post with the answer. I'm using this command and it's working: `mutt -e  'set from=cloudops@noreply.company.com realname="Cloud Ops" content_type=text/html' -c "$cc_address" -s "Welcome To Company AWS Account $aws_account" -- "$email_address"`